# How do I delete a file named "°" in bash

Tags: linux, bash, filenames

I've accidentally created a file named `°`. Now I'm having trouble deleting it with bash.

```
[/opt/etc/sudoers.d] # ls -l
-r--r-----    1 admin    administ       21 Feb  3 23:54 010-root
-rw-r--r--    1 admin    administ       20 Feb  3 23:50 °
```

Typing `rm °` seems to only move the caret to the beginning of the line, i.e. no character is entered.

(For what it's worth I'm running bash 3.2.0 on a remote machine conntected with SSH using Mac OSX Terminal)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about?

```
rm -i ?
```

I think this should work...

Comment: For further explanation, `-i` means "interactive". It will prompt you for each matching file before deleting it.

Comment: Great idea, but I had to replace `?` with `*` to make it work. `rm: cannot remove '?': No such file or directory`. What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps your locale is wrong and so your shell sees the degree/ring symbol as two characters rather than one.  Again, what does `locale -a` print?

Comment: Actually, the output of `locale` without `-a` would be better.

Answer (score 10):

If there are a lot of matches to using a wildcard with rm like `rm -i ?`, you can always remove it by inode number instead:

`ls -i` 
`find . -inum <inode> -ok rm '{}' \;`

Where `<inode>` is the inode number from `ls -i`, which lists all the inode numbers of the files in the current directory.

Comment: oh, this is cool.

Comment: This is the best answer since it gives a handle to the file itself.  Also, I never knew about the -ok flag!

Answer (score 2):

The `rm -i ?` answer is fine.

This would also work:

```
rm [^a-z]
```

as would

```
rm [[:punct:]]
```

---

And as to why it's going back to the start of the line, how are you typing the `˚`?  Perhaps the input is being interpreted as `Ctrl+A` or some other shortcut that is used by the shell to go to the start of the line.

Is there a setting to set the encoding or character set to `utf-8` in the terminal app?  What does it print if you run `locale` inside the terminal session?

---

And how did you create the file?  Maybe you can use a similar method to delete it?